# Query CONTAINS not working only selecting where equals

Tags: google-sheets-query

Queries using contains have recently stopped working correctly. 
When value in source data column is `1,2,3` and the query is `WHERE B contains '3'`

See test sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tCJBerHOmVfKbtb81JEyWEp6ZYP0EXyJqG-_7zVWpLw/edit?usp=sharing

**Update**
It appears that google is now first applying the Number Formatting to the cell then running the QUERY. Ensure your data column is set to PLAIN TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Update Google has changed to now first run the "Number Format" filters, then the QUERY method runs on the field. 
So by default AUTOMATIC NUMBER formatting is applied - google based on the value sets the format on what it thinks is correct.

FIX: Set data to `FORMAT > NUMBER > PLAIN TEXT`

I have updated the example to illustrate this.

This change would probably assist the general Google Sheets user, but where you are working off raw data ensure you set the PLAIN TEXT number format on the columns.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, add say `z` (any text) into B7 and `John` should appear in the output of your query.

Comment: sorry that did not work - its todo with number formats, see answer below